# Trying to use $_GET to display a row's information from a db table

Tags: php, sql, get

I'm extrememly new to php in general, so I realize some of this may seem "dumb", but please bear with me.

I have a page that's integrated with phpBB forums, so it uses their templating system, so I have no need to echo any html within a php page. Also, every page includes a connection to the database, so I have no need to put any connections.

On the html page, I'm using bits like {NAME} and {AGE} to pull up the information, but my problem lies with the php file itself. I want the page's url to have something like "file.php?name=John", where it will display the data within the row for "John" from the database.

Here is the code I'm currently using. Assuming most of this isn't horribly wrong to begin with, I'm getting an error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING" on what is line 2 of this code.

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$result = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM 'people' WHERE 'name' = $name);
while($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
{
$template->assign_vars(array(
'NAME'          => $row['name'],
'AGE'           => $row['age'],
    ));
}
```

I'm using a table called "people", and have two columns titled "name" and "age", of course. If anyone can tell me my mistakes or at least guide me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: missing some quote marks: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: your code is also vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: @Uku Loskit: no it's not. Syntactically incorrect code is 100% vulnerabilities free.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotes and some security:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE `name` = '$name'");
```

Although try to learn PDO or MySQLi for new code, it's inherently more secure.

Comment: You are missing quotes as well (assuming `name` column is a string)

Comment: Nope, backticks are for identifiers, not string literals

Comment: Fixed, I answered and then realized of the many small mistakes

Comment: In this example, the page will have multiple php warnings for "mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]:" and also stops the connection to the database.